# Nodejs-Express, PHP-Laravel, JWT Authentication depending on browser?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, nginx, jwt

i've got following issue:

my website is divided into Mainpages www.example.com (PHP-Laravel) and chat-application www.sub.example.com (with subdomain written in nodejs).

For authentication im using JWT and dotnev(connect to laravel .env file).

within my TokenController:

```
 public function token(\Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth $auth)
    {

        if (!Sentinel::check())
        {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'not_logged_in'], 401);
        }
       ...
     }
```

When I'm login with Chrome on my Desktop-PC everything works fine and he goes further then the if-statement so in IE-11 and even on Safari (MacOs ElCapitan) its working absolulty with out problems, but if I login with Opera or with Chrome on my Android device I run in the error 401 not_logged_in. Any idea what im doing wrong, or what I'm missing? :)

More information: 
If I'm loggedin (doesn't matter which browser) and I'm doing: www.example.com\token (laravel route to token, i'll get the token :)
My server is running with nginx/reverse-proxy.

I used [this](https://m.dotdev.co/authenticate-laravel-5-user-account-in-nodejs-socket-io-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-f74009d612f8) tutorial to understand the exchange between laravel and nodejs.
Thank you very much for any help/ideas.